# Templatefile inside dashboard_body

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I was wondering if its possible to use templatefile inside of a dashboard_body resource. I'm trying the following.

```
     dashboard_body = <<EOF
{
  "widgets": [
    {
      "type": "metric",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 12,
      "height": 6,
      "properties": {
        "metrics": [
          templatefile("${path.module}/backends.tmpl", { instances = aws_instance.web })
        ],
        "period": 300,
        "stat": "Average",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "title": "EC2 Instance CPU"
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

With templatefile

```
%{ for instance in instances ~}
          [
            "AWS/EC2",
            "CPUUtilization",
            "InstanceId",
            "${instance.id}"
          ]
%{ endfor ~}
```

However I get the following error message when I run terraform apply.

> Error: "dashboard_body" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'e' in literal true (expecting 'r')
>
> on dashboards.tf line 1, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main":
> 1: resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use a template file. It looks like you have a small syntax error here:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/backends.tmpl", { instances = aws_instance.web })
```

You should wrap the entire function in an interpolation block, like so:

```
${templatefile("${path.module}/backends.tmpl", { instances = aws_instance.web })}
```